# Change multiple keys from dictionary, while doing timedelta operation in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, which the keys are integers. I arbitrarily changed one of the keys to a date, and I need to change the other keys.

Sample data:

```
{'C-STD-B&M-SUM': {datetime.date(2015, 7, 12): 0,
               -1: 0.21484699999999998,
               -2: 0.245074,
               -3: 0.27874}
```

Expected output:

```
{'C-STD-B&M-SUM': {datetime.date(2015, 7, 12): 0,
               datetime.date(2015, 7, 11): 0.21484699999999998,
               datetime.date(2015, 7, 10): 0.245074,
               datetime.date(2015, 7, 9): 0.27874}
```

Current code so far:

```
def change_start_date(dictionary_with_temporal_distribution):
    unsw_mid_year_end_date = datetime.date(2015, 7, 12)
    dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'][unsw_mid_year_end_date] = dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'][0]
    del dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'][0]
    for k, v in dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'].items():
```

Comment: Do you need the - in the Expected output as well? `-datetime.date()` ?

Comment: Nope, just edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like -

```
def change_start_date(dictionary_with_temporal_distribution):
    unsw_mid_year_end_date = datetime.date(2015, 7, 12)
    for k in list(dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'].keys()):
        dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'][unsw_mid_year_end_date + timedelta(days=k)] = dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'][k]
        del dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'][k]
```

Comment: I'm getting this: TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.date

Comment: make sure all the keys are integer before you do into loop. do not change the '0'th element before the loop

Comment: Fixed it, now I got: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Fixed for Python3 , we need to do `list(dictionary_with_temporal_distribution['C-STD-B&M-SUM'].keys())` for this to work in Python3

Comment: Copying your code I get: TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.date
I tried to comment out the line where I change the integer to date and then I get nothing as the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80130/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-iamfbpt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension syntax and transform and replace the keys:

```
dct = {datetime.date(2015, 7, 12): 0,
    -1: 0.21484699999999998,
    -2: 0.245074,
    -3: 0.27874}

def offset(offset, base):
    """Applies an offset in days to a base date.
        If the offset is already a date it is returned as is."""
    if type(offset) == datetime.date:
        return offset
    return base + datetime.timedelta(offset)

def offset_keys(dct, base):
    """Takes a dict and runs offset(key, base) on all keys"""
    return { offset(k, base): v for k, v in dct.items() }

pprint(offset_keys(dct, datetime.date(2015, 7, 12)))
```

> ```
> {datetime.date(2015, 7, 9): 0.27874,
>  datetime.date(2015, 7, 10): 0.245074,
>  datetime.date(2015, 7, 11): 0.21484699999999998,
>  datetime.date(2015, 7, 12): 0}
> ```

Comment: I get this: TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: str

Comment: Then you're not passing the correct dictionary to the method. Make sure you pass the one with the `datetime.date` and integers as keys and not the one with `"C-STD-B&M-SUM"` as it's only key